# Excel file with PivotTables - reduce size

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, pivot-table

I have an Excel file with several tabs, one of which has two PivotTables. The data source for the first table is a specific range of rows (not an entire column) and the second table is based on the first. The size of the file is ~12 MB. If I remove this tab with the PivotTables the size goes down to ~1 MB.

I have two related questions:

1. How can I select specific columns for the PivotTable in the data source? When I tried to do this in the Wizard I got a "Reference is not valid" error.
2. Are there any other methods to reduce the size of the file? It seems ridiculous that a file would increase 12-fold in size because of this tab.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two separate pivot caches which, considering the base data is the same, would effectively double the storage requirements unnecessarily.

[This article](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/cut-the-size-of-your-pivot-table-workbooks-in-half/) has some great tips which should help.

Comment: That's a very good article. My second pivot table is already based on the first. I actually ended up using the tip [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104308): turn off "Save Data With Table Layout". This reduced the size of my file to 2 MB, which is very adequate.

Thanks for the feedback.